FFmpeg - record from stream terminating unexpectedly using kokorin/Jaffree ffmpeg wrapper for Java
I am programming a Spring Boot Application using Maven and Java 21. I am trying to record a stream from a url and save it to a mkv file. I intend to do this with kokorin/Jaffree in version 2023.09.10. The recording seems to work ok, however longer videos are terminating unexpectedly. Sometimes after 5 minutes, other times an hour or even longer. Sometimes with Exit Code 0 and sometimes with 1.
I have implemented the recording like this:
@Override
    public void startRecording(RecordingSchedule recordingSchedule) {
        logger.info("Starting recording for schedule with filename {}", recordingSchedule.getFileName());

        String m3uUrl = recordingSchedule.getM3uUrl();
        LocalDateTime endTime = timeUtils.parseStringToLocalDateTime(recordingSchedule.getEndTime());
        LocalDateTime stopTime = endTime.plusSeconds(20);
        String timeToRecord = timeUtils.calculateTimeToRecord(stopTime);
        Path outputPath = Paths.get("/recordings/" + recordingSchedule.getFileName());

        try {
            FFmpeg.atPath()
                  .addInput(UrlInput.fromUrl(m3uUrl))
                  .addArgument("-xerror")
                  .addArguments("-reconnect", "5")
                  .addArguments("-reconnect_streamed", "5")
                  .addArguments("-reconnect_delay_max", "20")
                  .addArguments("-t", timeToRecord)
                  .addArguments("-c", "copy")
                  .addOutput(
                      UrlOutput.toPath(outputPath))
                  .setLogLevel(LogLevel.WARNING)
                  .execute();
            logger.info("Recording complete. Output file: {}", outputPath.toAbsolutePath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error recording M3U stream {}: {}", recordingSchedule.getFileName(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

And I am calling the method like this:
executorConfig.executorService().submit(() -> ffmpegService.startRecording(recording));
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Here are the log lines at the beginning and end of recording of the past two attempts:
2024-04-18T00:54:48.689+02:00  INFO 1 --- [pool-2-thread-1] m.s.r.service.impl.FfmpegServiceImpl     : Starting recording for schedule with filename Example1.mkv
2024-04-18T00:54:48.697+02:00  WARN 1 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.github.kokorin.jaffree.ffmpeg.FFmpeg   : ProgressListener isn't set, progress won't be reported
2024-04-18T00:54:48.698+02:00  INFO 1 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.k.jaffree.process.ProcessHandler     : Command constructed:
ffmpeg -loglevel level+warning -i http://example.stream.url.com -n -xerror -reconnect 5 -reconnect_streamed 5 -reconnect_delay_max 20 -t 10771 -c copy /recordings/Example1.mkv
2024-04-18T00:54:48.698+02:00  INFO 1 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.k.jaffree.process.ProcessHandler     : Starting process: ffmpeg
2024-04-18T00:54:48.701+02:00  INFO 1 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.k.jaffree.process.ProcessHandler     : Waiting for process to finish
2024-04-18T01:31:02.633+02:00  WARN 1 --- [         StdErr] c.g.k.jaffree.process.BaseStdReader      : [h264 @ 0x559cd22dd940] [warning] Increasing reorder buffer to 2
2024-04-18T01:31:02.633+02:00  INFO 1 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.g.k.jaffree.process.ProcessHandler     : Process has finished with status: 0
2024-04-18T01:31:02.734+02:00  INFO 1 --- [pool-2-thread-1] m.s.r.service.impl.FfmpegServiceImpl     : Recording complete. Output file: /recordings/Example1.mkv

2024-04-18T03:54:48.678+02:00  INFO 1 --- [pool-2-thread-2] m.s.r.service.impl.FfmpegServiceImpl     : Starting recording for schedule with filename Example2.mkv
2024-04-18T03:54:48.678+02:00  WARN 1 --- [pool-2-thread-2] c.github.kokorin.jaffree.ffmpeg.FFmpeg   : ProgressListener isn't set, progress won't be reported
2024-04-18T03:54:48.678+02:00  INFO 1 --- [pool-2-thread-2] c.g.k.jaffree.process.ProcessHandler     : Command constructed:
ffmpeg -loglevel level+warning -i http://example.stream.url.com/ -n -xerror -reconnect 5 -reconnect_streamed 5 -reconnect_delay_max 20 -t 11431 -c copy /recordings/Example2.mkv
2024-04-18T03:54:48.678+02:00  INFO 1 --- [pool-2-thread-2] c.g.k.jaffree.process.ProcessHandler     : Starting process: ffmpeg
2024-04-18T03:54:48.679+02:00  INFO 1 --- [pool-2-thread-2] c.g.k.jaffree.process.ProcessHandler     : Waiting for process to finish
2024-04-18T04:57:22.256+02:00  WARN 1 --- [         StdErr] c.g.k.jaffree.process.BaseStdReader      : [h264 @ 0x55707ba988c0] [warning] Increasing reorder buffer to 3
2024-04-18T04:58:47.455+02:00 ERROR 1 --- [         StdErr] c.g.k.jaffree.process.BaseStdReader      : [NULL @ 0x55707ba988c0] [error] Picture timing SEI payload too large
2024-04-18T04:58:47.456+02:00 ERROR 1 --- [         StdErr] c.g.k.jaffree.process.BaseStdReader      : [NULL @ 0x55707ba988c0] [error] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
2024-04-18T04:58:47.456+02:00  WARN 1 --- [         StdErr] c.g.k.jaffree.process.BaseStdReader      : [matroska @ 0x55707ba9a380] [warning] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
2024-04-18T04:58:47.456+02:00 ERROR 1 --- [         StdErr] c.g.k.jaffree.process.BaseStdReader      : [matroska @ 0x55707ba9a380] [error] Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
2024-04-18T04:58:47.463+02:00 ERROR 1 --- [         StdErr] c.g.k.jaffree.process.BaseStdReader      : [error] av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
2024-04-18T04:58:47.463+02:00  INFO 1 --- [pool-2-thread-2] c.g.k.jaffree.process.ProcessHandler     : Process has finished with status: 1
2024-04-18T04:58:47.564+02:00 ERROR 1 --- [pool-2-thread-2] m.s.r.service.impl.FfmpegServiceImpl     : Error recording M3U stream Example2.mkv: Process execution has ended with non-zero status: 1. Check logs for detailed error message.

They were supposed to run nearly 3 hours and the other one over 3 hours. And with the timestamps you can see that they are not running nearly as long.
Thank you for your help!
